# Format currency as CNH in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, currency-format

I have some Excel cells in the currency CNH (offshore Renminbi). However, this is not available among the currency choices (Right-click->Format cells->Currency->Symbol). How can I use CNH in the excel  cell?

I am using Microsoft Excel 2013.

Answer (score 2):

It's character code 165 I think.  In excel, Alt-I S will pop up the symbol dialogue to let you find it...

You might be able to add a new currency symbol system-wide in Control Panel->Region And Language->Formats->Additional Settings->Customize Format->Currency Symbol

Hope this helps.